# Case Insensitive REPLACE for MySQL

Tags: mysql, replace

Is there a case insensitive `Replace` for MySQL?

I'm trying to replace a user's old username with their new one within a paragraph text.

```
$targetuserold = "@".$mynewusername;
$targetusernew = "@".$newusername;

$sql = "
    UPDATE timeline 
    SET message = Replace(message,'".$targetuserold."', '".$targetusernew."')
";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

This is missing the instances where the old username is a different case. Example: replacing "Hank" with "Jack" in all the rows in my database will leave behind instances of "hank".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution ultimately was that **I cannot do a case insensitive `Replace`.**

However, **I did find a workaround.**

I was trying to have a feature where a user can change their username. The system would then need to update wherever `@oldusername` was found in all the messages in the database.

The problem was... people wouldn't type other people's usernames in the correct case that it is found in the `members` table. So when the user would change their username, it wouldn't catch those instances of `@oldSeRNAmE` because of it not matching the case of the real format of the `oldusername`.

**I don't have permission with my GoDaddy shared server** to do this with a customized SQL function, so I had to find a different way.

**My solution:** Upon inserting new messages into the database, whenever a username is found in the new message, I have an `UPDATE` statement at that point to replace the username they typed with the correct formatted case that is found in the `members` table. That way, if that person ever wants to change their username in the future, all the instances of that username in the database will all be the same exact formatted case. Problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

An easier way that works without any stored function:

```
SELECT message,
       substring(comments,position(lower('".$targetuserold."') in message) ) AS oldval
  FROM timeline
 WHERE message LIKE '%".$targetuserold."%'
```

gives you the exact, case sensitive spellings of the username in all messages. As you seem to run that from a PHP script, you could use that to collect the spellings together with the corresponding IDs, and then run a simple `REPLACE(message,'".$oldval.",'".$targetusernew."')` on that. Or use the above as sub-select:

```
UPDATE timeline 
    SET message = REPLACE(
                   message,
                   (SELECT substring(comments,position(lower('".$targetuserold."') in message))),
                   '".$targetusernew."'
                  )
```

Works like a charm here.

<sub>Credits given to [this article](http://fuel-efficient-vehicles.org/pwsdb/?p=339), where I got the idea from.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Here it is:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `replace_ci`$$
CREATE FUNCTION `replace_ci` ( str TEXT,needle CHAR(255),str_rep CHAR(255))
    RETURNS TEXT
    DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        DECLARE return_str TEXT DEFAULT '';
        DECLARE lower_str TEXT;
        DECLARE lower_needle TEXT;
        DECLARE pos INT DEFAULT 1;
        DECLARE old_pos INT DEFAULT 1;

        SELECT lower(str) INTO lower_str;
        SELECT lower(needle) INTO lower_needle;
        SELECT locate(lower_needle, lower_str, pos) INTO pos;
        WHILE pos > 0 DO
            SELECT concat(return_str, substr(str, old_pos, pos-old_pos), str_rep) INTO return_str;
            SELECT pos + char_length(needle) INTO pos;
            SELECT pos INTO old_pos;
            SELECT locate(lower_needle, lower_str, pos) INTO pos;
        END WHILE;
        SELECT concat(return_str, substr(str, old_pos, char_length(str))) INTO return_str;
        RETURN return_str;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Usage:

```
$sql = "
    UPDATE timeline 
    SET message = replace_ci(message,'".$targetuserold."', '".$targetusernew."')
";
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the syntax of that function description. How would I implement that into my PHP script? Is that in PHP?

Comment: @tomuky No, it is an SQL query which your mySql server should run on your database. You just need to make sure that you first run the `CREATE FUNCTION replace_ci` script before running any script against that function.

Comment: I don't know how to have my MySQL server run this SQL query on my database. Can this be done in PHP? Any helpful reading material for me to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: Tried running this query and I received this error:
#1419 - You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled (you *might* want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creators variable)

Comment: @tomuky It's related to your current permissions on this database. Try to google it.

Comment: I'm using a shared server with GoDaddy. It appears that I cannot adjust permissions. This solution is not possible for me. If you know of any other methods, please share. Thanks!